# Laravel Eloquent - Inserting multiple records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do we insert multiple records using eloquent in Laravel?

Basically this:

```
            Teacher::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'college_id' => $collegeId,
                'first_name' => $this->faker->firstName(),
                'last_name' => $this->faker->lastName()
            ],[...],[...]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just came across the github request where Taylor replied that it is not possible with Eloquent and to use Query builder instead.

Here is the link to the issue:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1295

Comment: Yep, however mind that you won't get any `Eloquent` features with this - timestamps, events etc.